# Azure - GCP - connection via Openvpn

Tags: azure, openvpn, azure-networking

I need to create connection between `GCP` and `Azure` cloud. There in Open vpn connection created between `GCP` and `Azure` cloud, `OpenVPN` azure IP is `10.5.1.5`.

In `Azure` I have core `vnetA` and satelite `vnetB`. Between `vnetA` and `vnetB` I have peering configured, gateway transit is enabled on both sides of peered vnets.

I have two route tables: `RTableA`, `RTableB`.

RTableA is associated with `subnetA` in `vnetA`, `RTableB` is associated with `subnetB` in `vnetB`.

In `RTableA` I have routes:

- 1.(Name `GCPtraffic`;addr.prefix `192.168.0.0/24`;virtual appliance/openvpn IP `10.5.1.5`),
- 2.(Name `InternetGateway`;addr.prefix `0.0.0.0/0`; `Internet`),
- 3.(`Name Local`; addr.prefix `10.5.1.0/24`; `Virtual Network`).

In RTableB I have only one route

- 1.(Name `GCPtraffic`;addr.prefix `192.168.0.0/24`;virtual appliance/openvpn IP `10.5.1.5`).

I have VMs: `VmA` located in `subnetA`, `VmB` located in `subnetB`.

I have connection both directions `VmA` --> `VmB`, `VmB` --> `VmA`, and I can connect `VmA` --> GCP network.

Problem is that I am not able to connect `VmB` --> `GCP` network. Is there any route missing in that scenario?

Comment: Hello and welcome to serverfault. I just started to edit your question and realized I'd have to modify too much of it, that may change the meaning. Please edit your question and spend some time on proper formatting. Thx!

Comment: I think now it looks better and its clear to read.